# Calling a method on an attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessor

I am working on a tutorial and I wanted to really learn by deviating from the tutorial a bit and am encountering some problems.  I am creating a showtime app that lists all the movies, times, genres, etc.

I have a Movie model with the attributes name, genre, showtime, showdate, release year, and title.  In my movie.rb file, I added an attr_accessor :genre so I can use the setter and getter methods, but when I go into rails console and create a movie with all the attributes, the :genre keeps coming up as "nil" but when I call the movie.genre, it comes up as the correct listed genre.  I am not sure why that is?

Also, since genre is not a class, are there any methods I can call on it to list all the genres in the database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is genre a column in your movies table? If so, why use attr_accessor?

For the second part of your question, you could write a class method in movie.rb to list all genres. Something like:

```
def self.genres
  Movie.all.map(&:genre).uniq
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify Bill's first comment, if you are writing a ruby class, then you would use attr_accessor to establish the generic getter and setter for the attribute. This isn't necessary in Rails for the attributes that map to fields on your table. Rails will automatically imbue your model with generic getters and setters for all the fields on your database table. The only time you need to define your own is when you are adding attributes to the model that don't map to the table (why?), or when you need special processing in your getter/setter beyond the generic cases.

Comment: Thank you Bill for making it clearer to me how to use class methods.  Thanks Yardboy for the clarification between Ruby and Rails.  I guess attr_accessor is only necessary for things like password where it won't ever be stored in the database.

Comment: Correct about attr_accessors. Yardboy definitely explained it better, and it sounds like you've got a better handle on it now. But, yes, for things like passwords (or some other fields that aren't actually columns in the DB), the use of attr_accessor is perfectly fine.

Comment: If I do this using the class method, and put in:

'<% Movie.genres.each do |genre| %>
        <%=h genre %>
        <%= check_box_tag "genres[]" %></br>'

Because it's a form, when I click on one of the genre, it didn't save the genre. Is says it's nil.